# DML Operations on Indexes

Tags: sql, indexing

I understand that it is not advisable to create indexes on tables that will be frequently updated. However, does the same hold true for other DML operations? Is it recommended to create an index on a table that will have frequent INSERT and DELETE operations performed on it?

Comment: Your statement is probably true for the CLUSTERED index. But nothing is preventing you to create NONCLUSTERED index

Comment: Read about how indexes are maintained and this should become clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing overhead is highly dependent on table size, complexity and the number and size of the various INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations.

Sometimes it's faster to drop the indexes, perform the operations then recreate the indexes than it is to perform the operations with the indexes intact.

Other times it's slower.

You also need to weigh this against the impact on any SELECT operations that would be going on at the same time.

> "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of
>   it) in programming" (Knuth, 1974 Turing Award Lecture).

Until you're faced with actual performance problems that can't be fixed by improving your query, I'd ignore all the fringe-last-ditch-effort options like "not having indexes". Having the right indexes is almost always a performance improvement in normal operations.